# How to get spinner value to post form

Tags: android, string, post, spinner

i made this code so i can send information to my website. Only now i want to load the category from a spinner i tried:

String mCategory = category.getItemAtPosition(what to put here?).toString();

i just don't know how to, i'm hoping somebody does.

```
net.thinkbin;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class share extends Activity {

final Context context = this;
private Button post;
private EditText title, email, author, idea, submit;
Spinner category;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.share);

    Button view = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            startActivity(new Intent("net.thinkbin.TUTORIAL1"));
            overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
            finish();
        }
    });

    Button menu = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonhome);
    menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            // custom dialog
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);

            // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
            TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
            text.setText("Loading...");
            ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
            image.setImageResource(R.drawable.hourglass);

            dialog.show();
            Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    startActivity(new Intent("net.thinkbin.MENU"));
                    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    finish();

                }
            });
            th.start();
        }
    });

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(this, R.array.spinnerfood,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
     adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    Spinner s = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    s.setAdapter(adapter);

    post = (Button) findViewById(R.id.post);
    title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titlefield);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailfield);
    author = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.authorfield);
    category = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    idea = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ideafield);
    submit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.submitfield);
    post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            String mTitle = title.getText().toString();
            String mEmail = email.getText().toString();
            String mAuthor = author.getText().toString();
            String mCategory = category.getItemAtPosition().toString();
            String mIdea = idea.getText().toString();
            String mSubmit = submit.getText().toString();

            tryPost(mTitle, mEmail, mAuthor, mCategory, mIdea, mSubmit);
        }

    });
}



protected void tryPost(String mTitle, String mEmail, String mAuthor,
        String mCategory, String mIdea, String mSubmit) {
    HttpURLConnection connection;
    OutputStreamWriter request = null;

    URL url = null;
    String response = null;
    String parameters = "title=" + mTitle + "&email=" + mEmail + "&author="
            + mAuthor + "&category=" + mCategory + "&idea=" + mIdea
            + "&submit=" + mSubmit;

    try {
        url = new URL("http://www.thinkbin.net/include/api/share.php");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        request = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        request.write(parameters);
        request.flush();
        request.close();
        String line = "";
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(
                connection.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        // Response from server after login process will be stored in
        // response variable.
        response = sb.toString();
        // You can perform UI operations here
        Toast.makeText(this, "Succes! \n" + response, 0).show();
        isr.close();
        reader.close();
        startActivity(new Intent("net.thinkbin.MENU"));
        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
        finish();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Error

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bunch of `getSelected*()` [methods for the spinner](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getSelectedItem%28%29). You probably want `getSelectedItem()`.